# I am receiving an error when trying to save controller code in an Aura component but I am not sure how to resolve it

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am going through a Trailhead project to learn how to build an Aura Component for Salesforce.

I've copied the code from the Trailhead as instructed but when I go to save I receive an error.

My code:

```js
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {component.find("forceRecord").getNewRecord(
        "Property__c",
        null,
        false,
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.propertyRecord");
            var error = component.get("v.recordError");
            if (error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
        })
    );
    saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    var propBeds = parseInt(component.find('propBeds').get("v.value"), 10);
        var propBaths = parseInt(component.find('propBaths').get("v.value"), 10);
        var propPrice = parseInt(component.find('propPrice').get("v.value"), 10);
        component.set("v.propertyRecord.Name", component.find('propName').get("v.value"));    
        component.set("v.propertyRecord.Beds__c", propBeds);
        component.set("v.propertyRecord.Baths__c", propBaths);
        component.set("v.propertyRecord.Price__c", propPrice);
        component.set("v.propertyRecord.Status__c", component.find('propStatus').get("v.value"));
        var tempRec = component.find("forceRecord");
        tempRec.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
            console.log(result.state);
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            if (result.state === "SUCCESS") {
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Saved",
                    "message": "The record was saved."
                });
                resultsToast.fire();                
            } else if (result.state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(result.error));
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Error",
                    "message": "There was an error saving the record: " + JSON.stringify(result.error)
                });
                resultsToast.fire();
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + result.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(result.error));
            }
        }));
    }
```

Error is occuring starting at the line "saveRecord"

Here is the error I am receiving:

> Failed to save PropertyDialogController.js: ESLINT_ERROR:
> {c:PropertyDialog - CONTROLLER} line:col [15:24] --> Parsing error:
> Unexpected token ( : Source

I simply copied & pasted according to the trailhead not sure where I went wrong.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Functions must be separated by comma.
At the end of line before `saveRecord` you put `;` instead of  `,` and you forgot the closing bracket of `doInit` function.

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("forceRecord").getNewRecord(
        "Property__c",
        null,
        false,
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.propertyRecord");
            var error = component.get("v.recordError");
            if (error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
        })
    ); // Closing getNewRecord
},  // Closing doInit
saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help!

I completed the changes you suggested & I am still receiving the same error as before. It did not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
component.find("forceRecord").getNewRecord(
"Property__c",
null,
false,
$A.getCallback(function() {
var rec = component.get("v.propertyRecord");
var error = component.get("v.recordError");
if (error || (rec === null)) {
console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
return;
}
})
);

```
}
```

}) saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
var propBeds = parseInt(component.find('propBeds').get("v.value"), 10);
var propBaths = parseInt(component.find('propBaths').get("v.value"), 10);
var propPrice = parseInt(component.find('propPrice').get("v.value"), 10);
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Name", component.find('propName').get("v.value"));
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Beds__c", propBeds);
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Baths__c", propBaths);
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Price__c", propPrice);
component.set("v.propertyRecord.Status__c", component.find('propStatus').get("v.value"));
var tempRec = component.find("forceRecord");
tempRec.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
console.log(result.state);
var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
if (result.state === "SUCCESS") {
resultsToast.setParams({
"title": "Saved",
"message": "The record was saved."
});
resultsToast.fire();
} else if (result.state === "ERROR") {
console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(result.error));
resultsToast.setParams({
"title": "Error",
"message": "There was an error saving the record: " + JSON.stringify(result.error)
});
resultsToast.fire();
} else {
console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + result.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(result.error));
}
}));
}
})

Comment: Trailhead is for learning. Don't you agree a code dump like this is not very much encouraging such learning?